# npm install fails multiple times giving EPERM error

Tags: npm, windows-10, npm-install

npm-install is showing me this error lately and I have no clue. It used to work fine before. I'm using windows and tried running
npm install -g create-react-app

path C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging

npm ERR! code EPERM

npm ERR! errno -4048

npm ERR! syscall unlink

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging'

npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging']

npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging' }

npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).